# Unusual mass 301 redirects with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm migrating an old ecommerce site to a new shopping cart system... I need to 301 redirect all URL scenarios for SEO purposes.

I've got most of it handled, but I need some insight on whether this is the right technique for the task at hand (and whether my syntax looks correct)... there will be about 1000 rules in the htaccess.

Here's my general rule setup for each product page... there's multiple rules for each product because I'm consolidating old MENS / WOMENS pages into ONE new product page (as well as redirecting any of the various querystring versions of the original URL):

```
RewriteRule  /mens-shirts-77/alice-in-wonderland-shirt-589.html$ http://www.domain.com/alice-in-wonderland-shirt-p160c3 [R=301]
RewriteRule  /womens-shirts-92/womens-alice-in-wonderland-shirt-842.html$ http://www.domain.com/alice-in-wonderland-shirt-p160c3 [R=301]
RewriteRule  /index.php?main_page=product_info*&products_id=(589|842)*$ http://www.domain.com/alice-in-wonderland-shirt-p160c3 [R=301]
```

For reference, here's what the original query string looks like... "&cpath=##" no longer matters, since all products with category paths are being redirected to a Canonical root from now on... as well, the "hipid=" is just garbage:

```
/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=77&products_id=694&hipid=63ad73f32f5159a3d0f71b7b92404591
```

So I dunno, is all this correct? Will this many rules slow the site down? Is there anything I'm missing (this migration has a long SEO history = no room for mistakes)?

I'm also a little concerned with conflicts as the shopping cart system (OpenCart) is also doing it's URL rewriting from the querystring URL to the SEO URL... but that's so abstract, I can even begin to figure out who-is-doing-what-in-which-order. :/

Just looking for some insight, do these rules look right? Thanks!

Comment: Rules are fine, are you facing any problems?

Comment: Your 3rd `RewriteRule` is not correct. In order to match the query string you need to use the `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ....` directive. (But the regex doesn't look correct either?)